# Sending params using Javascript

Tags: javascript, http

I have the following code and it seems to be not sending any params with the request. Any ideas what could be the issue? This is just a part of the code and I have ensured the variables x, y and pos in the params are being received:

```
 const params = {
            lat: x,
            long: y,
            current:pos,

        };

      var xhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();


      xhttp.open("POST","http://example.com/test/",true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));
      location.reload(true);
```

The POST request gets received on the server but there's no params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XMLHttpRequst.send()` method takes a `FormData` object as an input parameter, whereas you are passing a string to it. You can pretty simply convert your object to a FormData object using this statement:

```js
var data = new FormData();
for(var key in params){
    data.append(key,params[key]);
}
```

Then with that, all you need to do is call `send()` on your new FormData object:

```js
xhttp.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = "test";
var y = "anothertest";
var pos = "testAgain";
const params = {
  lat: x,
  long: y,
  current: pos
};

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://example.com/test?";
for (var i in params) {
  if(params[i])
      url += i+"="+params[i]+"&";
}
console.log(url);
// Uncomment the following lines
//xhttp.open("POST",url,true);
//xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
//location.reload(true);
```